# Any simple frameworks for pagination in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pagination

I want to find a framework for pagination in Google App Engine.

Do you know of one?

Comment: Have you tried doing pagination by yourself?  It's a pretty simple task, it should be easy to do without requiring someone else to write it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination is not always easy-to-do, especially when you consider sorting and filtering.  Check out this recipe as a start: http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/efficient-paging-for-any-query-and-any-model/

Comment: @Jason Hall
If you take the time to read the article you link to, you will notice that the article itself actually links to a group discussion on a framework for doing easy pagination without custom properties.  Oh, and the code in that group is the gaefy Pager that I reference in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do paging you should read about  [cursors.](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Query_Cursors)
The article linked to by Jason was written before cursors were around.  Cursors can simplify paging greatly, especially in cases that Andrew mentions, when dealing with sorts and filters.